# kubuntu 16.04 wifi scanner?

Tags: wireless, 16.04, kubuntu

Just took home an old Lenovo "ideapad" with Kubuntu 16.04 installed, and cannot connect to my wifi router.

1. Is there a scanner available?  The connection editor is not looking for routers in range.
2. when I type in the SSID and WPA-2 password for my home router, I get an error as follows: connection.gateway-timeout-invalid  can not set property (and then it talks about a value of type 'guint' is out of range.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide further details. Visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos for how to collect.